# How to access exception recipients after initialisation with exception notification gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, exception-notification

I want to be able to define the `exception_recipients` dynamically, based on the Rails environment. For example:

```
recipients = Rails.env == 'production'
   exceptions@myapp.com
else
   User.current.email
end
```

However, from the docs:

```
Whatever::Application.config.middleware.use ExceptionNotification::Rack,
  :email => {
    :email_prefix => "[Whatever] ",
    :sender_address => %{"notifier" <notifier@example.com>},
    :exception_recipients => %w{exceptions@example.com}
  }
```

In `config/environments/production.rb` where i don't have an `ActiveRecord::Base` connection yet.

How can I set the exceptions recipients after Rails has loaded?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Custom Notifier

You can create a custom notifier, which inherits from the [`EmailNotifier`](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification/blob/master/lib/exception_notifier/email_notifier.rb), which will use `User.current.email` in the non-production environments.

```
# app/models/exception_notifier/custom_notifier.rb
#
module ExceptionNotifier
  class CustomNotifier < EmailNotifier

    def initialize(options)
      @fallback_exception_recipients = options[:fallback_exception_recipients]
      options[:exception_recipients] ||= options[:fallback_exception_recipients]
      super(options)
    end

    def call(exception, options = {})
      options[:exception_recipients] = [User.current.email] unless Rails.env.production?
      super(exception, options)
    end

  end
end
```

### Initializer

The fallback address can, for example, be passed from the initializer.

```
# config/initializers/exception_notification.rb
#
Rails.application.config.middleware.use ExceptionNotification::Rack, {
  :custom => {
    :fallback_exception_recipients => %w{exceptions@myapp.com},
    # ...
  }
}
```

### `current_user` instead of `User.current`

I'm not sure whether your `User.current` call will work here. But, you pass the `current_user` to the exception data as shown in the [README](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification#custom-data-eg-current-user).

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
#
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :prepare_exception_notifier
  private
  def prepare_exception_notifier
    request.env["exception_notifier.exception_data"] = {
      :current_user => current_user
    }
  end
end
```

Then, replace the above `ExceptionNotifier::CustomNotifier#call` method with this one:

```
# app/models/exception_notifier/custom_notifier.rb
#
module ExceptionNotifier
  class CustomNotifier < EmailNotifier

    # ...

    def call(exception, options = {})
      unless Rails.env.production?
        if current_user = options[:env]['exception_notifier.exception_data'][:current_user]
          options[:exception_recipients] = [current_user.email]
        end
      end
      super(exception, options)
    end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported out of the box.  You might be able to create your own custom notifier as described in the docs : https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification#custom-notifier

You can look at the built in `EmailNotifier` and potentially extend it and just override either the `initialize` or `compose_email` methods to make it do what you need.

https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification/blob/master/lib/exception_notifier/email_notifier.rb#L120

https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification/blob/master/lib/exception_notifier/email_notifier.rb#L90

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm looking at the custom notifier but am not sure how to use it. What method to i call in `call` to actually send the email? How do i access the options set for the custom notifier in `Whatever::Application.config.middleware.use ExceptionNotification::Rack`? Thanks